# Dynamic Summary for Swagger documentation

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

Trying to make a flexible way for documentation in .net core swagger when using shared code between services.
Please have a look at this example:

```
public abstract class Err
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The error x
    /// </summary>
    public abstract string Code { get; }
}

public class Err1 : Err
{
    public override string Code { get => "100"; }
}

public class Err2 : Err
{
    public override string Code { get => "200"; }
}

public class Err3 : Err
{
    public override string Code { get => "300"; }
}

[Route("api/test")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Err), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        int i = (new Random().Next(1, 11));
        if (1 < 4)
            return BadRequest(new Err1());
        if (i < 7)
            return BadRequest(new Err2());
        return Ok("OK");
    }
}
```

This will of course produce a swagger looking something like this:

[image]

What I would like to have instead is something like this:

[image]

So the important thing here is that the **code=300 is NOT included** in the summary, because it is not being used in this assembly.

So what I've been thinking of here is;

- Is it possible to do some reflection, find all inherited classes being used and write that to the XML (while compiling?) instead of the ordinary summary part?
- Override how Swagger read the summary and write your own code.
- Can you hook up some Swagger middleware to handle this so it does not read from the XML?

If the reflection part is not possible, of course the next best thing would be in some way to hardcode a list of all the Error-classes being used for this particular services.

Any ideas here guys?

Comment: Even if it is possible to dynamically generate that message, I don't think you'll be able to effectively filter out Code 300. It's not simple to know if a class is _used_ or not. Why don't you use the Code xml comment to explain to the user what the number are _and what they mean_? Would an enum be more effective?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to do this at all, if you put the abstract class (and the children) in some shared location - Swagger will always find the static "summary" text. It would be so weird to have copies of the Error classes in every service. The problem I have is that it must be relevant data, I can't say that "there is an error code 300" when this service will never give that back.

Comment: The images don't show the Swagger specification, they show the way it's rendered by one specific UI. By trying to influence the UI you're creating a bad Swagger document that will confuse clients. As for 400, ASP.NET Core already returns [validation errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0) based on RFC7231 and its parent class, [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: In fact, `ProblemDetails` should be the default return type for a 400 error. The Bad Request responses are explained in [Automatic HTTP 400 Responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
for the first part, what I understand it is not possible to find out if a class is used or not via reflection :(
And for the second part, if you replace the swashbuckle with nswag you are actually able to have this nice "one of" -feature in the swagger UI :) But in my case that is not enough so I guess this is not possible right now.